# Quarkus/JAX-RS: possible to get better data binding errors?

Tags: validation, data-binding, jax-rs, quarkus

I am currently working on a Quarkus application using JSON-B and I am doing something like the following:

```
public class Something {

    public enum Choice { X, Y, Z }

    private Choice a;
    private Choice b;
    private Choice c;

    // getters and setters omitted
}

@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TestResource {

    @POST
    public Response post(@Valid Something something) {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

The following request results correctly in an exception:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/test
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
  "a": "X",
  "b": "TEST",
  "c": "TEST2"
}

javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY008200: JSON Binding deserialization error: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Internal error: No enum constant com.example.Something.Choice.TEST
```

The problem with this is, that the `JsonbException` is thrown right when the first datatype conversion fails. From a validation and response standpoint I don't like this very much, as I would rather know EVERY attribute that is invalid (b and c).

**Is there a way to make JSON-B deserialization report multiple errors?**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, there is no way to get a better error message.